Get headers in aspect in reactive web app
Is there any possibility to get headers in aspect?
    @Around("@within(reactivefeign.spring.config.ReactiveFeignClient)")
        suspend fun handle(pjp: ProceedingJoinPoint) = withTraceContext {
        //I need headers here
        pjp.proceed()
    }

Something like
ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes = (ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();

In non-reactive apps
Thanks in advance

Is it possible to use a filter instead of an aspect? Since filters have access to ServerWebExchange, you can extract all necessary information directly from there.

nope, I need to change feign client's base url via reflection based on request headers

Are you looking to wrap your Feign client in a proxy to dynamically change the base URL based on request headers?

yes, thats exactly what I need
